# Forcing certain environment variable to be defined when a specific Makefile rule is invoked

Tags: makefile

Consider the Makefile below.

```
rulea:
    echo rulea

ruleb:
    echo ruleb
```

I want an environment variable `SPL_VAR` to be defined when `ruleb` is invoked, or abort otherwise. When `rulea` is invoked, it should not enforce this constraint. How can I achieve the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first assume that "*defined*" means "*does not expands as the empty string*", and that "*abort*" means "*stop and exit with a non-zero exit status*".

**Solution 1**: You can achive this using the shell conditionals:

```
ruleb:
    @if [ -n "$$SPL_VAR" ]; then \
        echo ruleb; \
    else \
        echo "SPL_VAR undefined, aborting"; \
        exit 1; \
    fi
```

**Solution 2**: A more compact form of the same idea:

```
rulec:
    @[ -n "$$SPL_VAR" ] && echo rulec || \
    { echo "SPL_VAR undefined, aborting"; exit 1; }
```

**Solution 3**: Make documentation says:

> Every environment variable that make sees when it starts up is transformed into a make variable with the same name and value.

So, you can also use make conditionals:

```
ruled:
ifeq ($(SPL_VAR),)
    $(error "SPL_VAR undefined, aborting")
else
    @echo ruled
endif
```

**Solution 4**: Finally, you can also use the make `if` function:

```
rulee:
    $(if $(SPL_VAR),@echo rulee,$(error "SPL_VAR undefined, aborting"))
```

**Demo**:

```
host> unset SPL_VAR
host> make ruleb
SPL_VAR undefined, aborting
make: *** [Makefile:4: ruleb] Error 1
host> make rulec
SPL_VAR undefined, aborting
make: *** [Makefile:12: rulec] Error 1
host> make ruled
Makefile:17: *** "SPL_VAR undefined, aborting".  Stop.
host> make rulee
Makefile:23: *** "SPL_VAR undefined, aborting".  Stop.
host> export SPL_VAR=foo
host> make ruleb rulec ruled rulee
ruleb
rulec
ruled
rulee
```

**Note**: if "*abort*" means "*do nothing for this rule but do not stop*", just replace `exit 1` by `exit 0` and `$(error ...)` by `$(warning ...)` in the 4 proposed solutions.

Comment: Have you tried adding `rulea` and invoking that? Per my specification, it should not be needing `SPL_VAR` set.

Comment: I didn't try because I know it will work as you expect.

Comment: I think Solution 3 and 4 are not applicable because Makefile conditionals are more like pre-processor directives which are parsed and processed regardless of the rule invoked.

Comment: Also `exit 1` doesn't abort processing of the rule, unfortunately. It exits from the sub-shell.

Comment: @Holmes.Sherlock: Solutions 3 and 4 impact only the rules they cover. Give them a try and you will see by yourself. And `exit 1` exits the sub-shell, you are right, but as there is only one sub-shell in the rule, it does what you want. Here again, just copy-paste and try, you will see by yourself.

Comment: @Holmes.Sherlock: you used spaces instead of tabs in `rulec`. Remember that make recipes are prefixed with tabs.

Comment: Works with tabs. What was the problem with spaces?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173384/discussion-between-renaud-pacalet-and-holmes-sherlock).

Comment: Just note: _if your shell is bash_ is not relevant: `make` always uses `/bin/sh` regardless of what the user's shell is set to.  Unless you really meant, _if your system uses bash as its /bin/sh_, but the only thing in your solution that needs bash is `[[ ]]` and you don't use any special features, so you could just use `[ ]` and be portable and not need to worry about it.

Comment: @MadScientist: you're right, of course, my phrasing was not clear. I meant "_if the shell that make uses_", not the user's shell. And yes, `sh` and `[]` would work the same. I modify my answer accordingly. Thanks.